# uniform convergence, compactness problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a sequence of continuous functions and $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact. Suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $K$. Show that $f(K)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(K)$ is compact.

My initial thought was that $f$ is continuous, since $f_n$ are continuous and converge uniformly to $f$. So $f(K)$ is compact, and $f_n(K)$ is compact for each $n$, but a countable union of compact sets is not necessarily compact. Can someone provide a hint with how to proceed?

Comment: That should be "on $K$" at the end of your second sentence, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the union is both closed and bounded. A tip that should help for both: given $\epsilon>0$, the union is contained in

$\{x: dist(x, f(K))\leq \epsilon\} \cup f_1(K) \cup \cdots \cup f_N(K)$

for large $N$.